# Generate UML Component Diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, component-diagram

I'm trying to find a library that creates UML Component Diagram using a config file (XML, Lua, whatever... )

My objective is reach something like this:
[image]
*UML Component Diagram from [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409390.aspx)*

I already found [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/component.html), but i can't represent Composite Components on it.
Does someone have another project ?

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to find something like [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), and I could the code below. You can try the code using [online Graphviz](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/)

```
graph ER {
  SuperComponent [shape=component]
  node SuperComponent {
    comp1 [shape=component]
        facet1 [shape=circle, height=0.12,width=0.12, label=""]
        facet2 [shape=circle, height=0.12,width=0.12, label=""]
    comp1 -- facet1 [label="My Facet1" fontsize=6];
    comp1 -- facet2 [label="My Facet2" fontsize=6];    
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. How do you intend to generate the "XML, Lua, whatever..." so that the desired tool could create the diagram? Do you have any other tool which generates any kind of XMI?

Comment: @gustavogbc: I tried to give a bit more explanation